# Is there way to keep the iPad screen on?

Tags: ipad, power-management

Is there a way to prevent the iPad from sleeping while my app runs? I am making a kiosk app that needs to not auto sleep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]
```

Comment: Does this only affect the iPad when my app is running? Do I need to change this back on application exit?

Answer (score 2):

You want the `UIApplication.idleTimerDisabled` property.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to `igul222`s answer.

Comment: It only affects the iPad while your app is running.